# Serving video files using Cloud Storage and Cloud CDN

Tags: google-cloud-storage, avplayer, flutter-video-player, google-cloud-load-balancer, google-cloud-cdn

Update: I've come up with something of a fix.

I added the following to the http headers I was sending

"If-None-Match": "1"

This forces a cache miss when AVPlayer sends it's initial byte range request to retrieve the first byte and thus the response has all the data it needs to start playback (Content-Length, Content-Type, Content-Range).

This is a hack, and causes cache misses on other requests as well. I will leave the question unanswered as it'd be great to get to an actual solution. One thing I think might help would be to set this on the URL requests in AVPlayer

NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData

However operation at the abstraction level of Flutter's VideoPlayer I could not find a way to do this. There are probably changes that could be made at the Cloud CDN level as well but I've yet to find one that works.

---

Update: I believe I know what is causing this behavior. When AVPlayer sends it's first request with Range: bytes=0-1 there are two cases:

1. Server responds with 304 response code, and response headers containing only Age, Etag, Cache-Control and Date. In this case AVPlayer will send another request to download the entire mp4 before playing (presumably because it has no idea what kind of file/size of the file it has been asked to play)
2. Server responds with a 206 response code and all the necessary headers populated. In this case the player will play the video basically instantly and send multiple requests to the server to pull down the video in small chunks until it is done playing. Here are screen captures to make it more concrete.

Response code 304
[image: Case1]

Response code 206
[image: Case2]

So I think this problem breaks down to, why is the server responding with 304 for some initial byte range requests and how can it respond with 206 and the needed content each time instead?

---

I am developing a Flutter app where users can view uploaded mp4 files from Cloud Storage. I have setup a Global external application load balancer with Cloud CDN and my Cloud Storage bucket as the backend origin. My flutter application requests files from cloud storage by sending HTTP requests to the external IP exposed by the load balancer.

On Android this works great. Video files load very fast. On iOS the device downloads the entire file before it starts playing. On a WIFI signal this results in a 1-5 second delay while on 5G it can be 10-100 seconds. I modified my code so that instead of going through the application load balancer it requests the files directly from Cloud Storage. Doing this the files load quickly (maybe 1 second delay) although not as quickly as when going thorough CDN and leveraging the cache.

I have inspected the network requests and it looks like when AvPlayer sends it's first byte range request (Range bytes=0-1) Cloud Storage returns an appropriate response and type (Content-Type: video/mp4) whereas for the same request Cloud CDN returns a text/plain response with a Age, Etag, Cache-Control and Date.

Any idea what would cause cloud CDN to return that response?

Comment: Pleas include the HTTP request including headers for each example you show.

Comment: Hey John. Using the inspection tool I have I don't have access to request/response bytes, just the headers.

Comment: Use the CLI `curl`. Very good debugging tools for HTTP and other protocols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get a 304 response is because the request sent by AVPlayer includes an `if-none-match` header, and one of the caches has a response with a matching etag.

The request from AVPlayer is specifically asking for a 304 response if any cache happens to have a response with the given etag. (See [RFC9110/13.1.2](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9110.html#field.if-none-match).) Generally, a client (such as AVPlayer) only sends an `if-none-match` request because it has a cached copy--it's just checking whether there's a newer one. The 304 response should cause AVPlayer to use the response it had previously cached.

You say that this is AVPlayer's first request. If AVPlayer doesn't already have a cached response, then it shouldn't send `if-none-match` (or `if-modified-since`) headers. If it does have a cached response, it should play it. Either way, this looks like a bug in the Flutter app, AVPlayer, or somewhere in between. I suggest that you figure out why the `if-none-match` header is present.

Comment: Hi Todd, I agree this seems to be some issue in my Flutter code/the Flutter  video_player or AvPlayer. I will open a issue on the Flutter video_player and see if they have some insight. I'll accept your response as it does seem the issue is that AVPlayer is using some cached response when it shouldn't. I do know I am serving the videos using byte range caching and this cache setting explicitly states it is important to be set when using byte ranges. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/cachepolicy/reloadignoringlocalcachedata

Answer (score 0):

Cloud CDN caches only responses with cacheable content. This information is conveyed in HTTP response headers, in combination with the backend configuration. If responses for a URL aren't being cached, check the headers returned for that URL and the **[cacheability](https://cloud.google.com/media-cdn/docs/caching#cache-modes)**  for your backend.

You can use the `curl` command as `curl -s -D - -o /dev/null http://example.com/image.png` and this will help you to analyze different types of scenarios related to HTTP response headers like `Content-Type,Content-Length,Cache-Control,Age,etag` as mentioned in the official **[Troubleshoot Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/troubleshooting-steps)** documentation.

You can also refer to this official GCP doc on **[Change cache modes | Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-cache-modes#cache-mode)** for more information.

Comment: Thanks for responding Kiran. I will try using curl to inspect some responses and comment again if anything interesting comes up.

Comment: Hi Kiran, I updated my post with my new findings.

Comment: The [SF link](https://serverfault.com/a/571557/999195) has the information regarding Response code 206. Can you look into it and let me know if it is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

What content MIME type is your object showing on GCS? One option to consider is changing the [CDN cache mode](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching#cache-modes) on you backend bucket to FORCE_CACHE_ALL and see if that doesn't help. Based on what you are describing, I am suspecting that the [MIME type](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#content-type) isn't set properly on GCS object. You can always try forcing the MIME type in GCS and see if that doesn't help with the CACHE_ALL_STATIC mode (whihc is the default policy for Cloud CDN). Changing the cache mode will ignore whatever MIME type the object is advertising and apply a cache control header for Cloud CDN which should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for responding Dave, I spot checked a few of my blobs in GCS and they have their Content-Type set to video/mp4. I will try changing the cache mode and see if that helps.

Comment: I have also noticed that when AVPlayer sends it's first request the response is a 304. I don't know if it can handle this correctly. When I use a different player based on MPV it sends/receives multiple 206s as it pulls down the video in little chunks.

Comment: Hi Dave, I updated my post with my new findings.